# How to link to an element in Lightning Out following Apex Controller callout

Tags: lightning, lightning-out

I have a component that works in the Lightning interface and I'm trying to modify it to also work in Lightning out for use in Classic Web and SF1 through VF Mobile Cards.

Currently, the component has a button. Once the user clicks the button, it fires off an Apex Controller method to create a record, then returns the new Records ID.

In the lightning component, it gets an instance of the e.force:navigateToSObject event and fires it with the new Id. However, in Lightning-Out the instance of that event comes back as null/undefined.

How should I forward the user to the new page?

In other lightning components that have been converted to support lightning out in VF, we've just used standard html anchor tags to allow the user to click through, but if I use that approach here, I am unable to get the element and fire a .click() event because of the locker service.

Here's some sample code:

```
<ui:button press="{!c.createAndForward}" ... />


createAndForward: function(component, event, helper){
    var action = component.get('c.serverCreate');
    action.setParmas({...});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var objId = response.getReturnValue();
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        if(navEvt){
            //We are inside Lightning Experience
            navEvt.setParams({"recordId":objId});
            navEvt.fire();
        }
        else{
            //We are inside Visualforce using Lightning Out.
            if(!(typeof sforce === "undefined")){
                //We are within the SF1 app
                sforce.one.navigateToSObject(objId,'detail');
            } 
            else {
                //What should be done inside here?
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
```

Comment: What does your code look like on your VF page to create the Lightning out

Answer (score 0):

Are you listening for the event?

In the app I am working on I had to add the following (for the navigate to URL event):

**App (Add dependency for the event)**

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
```

**VF Page (Portions removed for brevity)**

```
        $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c.AppName",
                {
                    "recordId": "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
                },
                "div Id",
                function (cmp) {
                    $A.eventService.addHandler({
                        event: 'force:navigateToURL',
                        handler: function (event) {
                            if (typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce.one) {
                                // VF page in S1 or Lightning Exp
                                // VF page in Classic
                                sforce.one.navigateToURL(event.getParams().url);

                            } else {
                                ......DO STUFF.....
                            }

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Did you do similar for the `navigatetoSObject` event

Comment: window.parent.location.href won't work because of cross domain exception.

Comment: @ScottMacWatters - In my implementation it works just fine (from a classic button loading the popup in an iframe). Feel free to modify as needed. The key point was the implementation of the event not the internals of what to do during the event. I will update to remove the confusion